# would like to know the difference between sh(hostname) and sh "hostname" in jenkins pipelines

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am using jenkins pipeline and below script in a thought of it would go inside the node and print out the hostname but

```
node {

    echo "Inside the machine"
    sh (hostname)
}
```

resulted failure and its saying ..

> [Pipeline] sh

[test_sh_in_pipelines] Running shell script

- c41f13de2853
  /var/jenkins_home/workspace/test_sh_in_pipelines@tmp/durable-f7fb0513/script.sh: line 1: c41f13de2853: not found

but it worked when i try

```
node {

    echo "Inside the machine"
    sh ("hostname")
}
```

- hostname
  c41f13de2853
  [Pipeline] }

please point out what happens when `sh()` starts interpreting

Answer (score 3):

In the first case hostname is treated as a variable, having the value "c41f13de2853". It tries to execute the value as a shell command, which obviously does not exist.

In the second case "hostname" is a literal string which has nothing to do with the variable, so it just executes it as a command. The hostname command, when executed, prints the actual hostname (c41f13de2853).